# Why was my laptop unable to turn on?

Tags: laptop, battery, power, battery-life, charging

I suspended Ubuntu on my laptop, and then carried it in my backpack to another place. Then I found that the laptop was off instead of being suspended. I couldn't  make it power on either, even with power from wall electricity.

I then removed the battery and then put it back, and then I could power it on

So what was the problem?

Is my battery dead? How can I check its health under Ubuntu 12.04?

If it is because my battery was loose, then why couldn't I turn on the laptop with wall electricity?

Comment: Sounds like loose connection.   Laptops don't like loosing power unexpectedly from their batteries.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the contact between the battery and your laptop was interrupted. Which looks logical, because of the possible shocks during the time when the laptop was in your backpack.

As long as it now works as normal, you shouldn't be worried about the battery.

Comment: Thanks! If it is because my battery was loose, then why couldn't I turn on the laptop with wall electricity?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not really sure. Maybe the charger charges directly the battery and if the battery wasn't connected, than it wasn't able to charge.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I didn't made myself clear. Let me clarify. First, I was unable to turn it on with battery "on" and wall electricity. Then I was able to turn it on after removing the battery and with wall electricity. At last, I was able to turn it on with  battery on and wall electricity. I didn't quite get it why I couldn't turn it on with battery "on" and wall electricity at the beginning